# Arraylist last element overwriting previous elements

Tags: java, jsf, arraylist

I have a code that allows teacher to add students and view them, but everytime I add a student, the previous student would get overwritten as well.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<h:body>
<h:form>
    <h1><label>Student Grades</label></h1>
    <hr />
    <h:dataTable value="#{course.studentList}" var="st" border="1" rendered="#{course.render}">
        <f:facet name="caption">#{course.courseCode} #{course.courseName}</f:facet>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Student Name</f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{st.studentName}" />
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Score</f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{st.studentScore}" />
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable><br />
    <label>Student Name</label>
    <h:inputText id="studentName" label="Student Name" value="#{student.studentName}" required="true" requiredMessage="Please enter a student name">
    </h:inputText>
    <h:message for="studentName" /><br />
    <label>Student Score</label>
    <h:inputText id="studentScore" label="Student Score" value="#{student.studentScore}" required="true" converterMessage="You must enter a number">
    <f:validateDoubleRange minimum="0" maximum="100" />
    </h:inputText>
    <h:message for="studentScore" /><br />
    <h:commandButton value="Add Grade" action="#{course.add(student)}"/>
    <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="summary"/>
</h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Below is the student.java

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean(name = "student")
@SessionScoped
public class Student {
private String studentName;
private Double studentScore;

public String getStudentName() {
    return studentName;
}

public void setStudentName(String studentName) {
    this.studentName = studentName;
}

public Double getStudentScore() {
    return studentScore;
}

public void setStudentScore(Double studentScore) {
    this.studentScore = studentScore;
}
}
```

Below is the Course.java which has an arraylist of students.

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import java.util.ArrayList;

@ManagedBean(name = "course")
@SessionScoped
public class Course {
private String courseName;
private String courseCode;
private ArrayList<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();
private double courseAverage;
private boolean render;

public String getCourseName() {
    return courseName;
}

public void setCourseName(String courseName) {
    this.courseName = courseName;
}

public String getCourseCode() {
    return courseCode;
}

public void setCourseCode(String courseCode) {
    this.courseCode = courseCode;
}

public ArrayList<Student> getStudentList() {
    return studentList;
}

public void setStudentList(ArrayList<Student> studentList) {
    this.studentList = studentList;
}

public double getCourseAverage() {
    int i = 0;
    for (Student st : studentList) {
        courseAverage += st.getStudentScore();
        i++;
    }
    return courseAverage/i;
}

public void setCourseAverage(double average) {
    this.courseAverage = average;
}

public boolean isRender() {
    return render;
}

public void setRender(boolean render) {
    this.render = render;
}

public String add(Student student) {
    studentList.add(student);
    render = true;
    return null;
}

public String reset() {
    studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();
    courseName = "";
    courseCode= "";
    courseAverage = 0.0;
    render = false;
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().invalidateSession();
    return "home";
}

public boolean renderable() {
    boolean render = false;
    for (Student st : studentList) {
        render = true;
    }
    return render;
}
}
```

Comment: where you are putting value in arrayList?

Comment: Make sure that the Course.reset method isn't getting called somehow...

Comment: @MuneebNasir if you look at the xhtml file, one of the command buttons calls the function course.add(student) which appends the student to the studentlist array

Comment: @karakuricoder the course.reset method is called in another xhtml file.

Comment: sorry man, i was ignoring scroll bar with Course Class

Answer (score 0):

As your `Student` class is annotated as a `@SessionScoped` `@ManagedBean`, it will be created and stored throughout the user's HTTP session, i.e. unless it is invalidated, or it expires. So, when you add a value to your list you basically add a very same reference everywhere and all you do is modify the fields of a `Student` object that was once created and later its fields were continuously replaced and, thus, *every* list element that contains a reference to *the same* `Student` object, was modified as well.

What you need to do is to create a brand new `Student` object that is to be added to the list and for this essentially removing any bean annotations from it.

As a side note, be sure to understand the differencebetween and use cases of a managed bean and a model/placeholder before you proceed any further.

Answer (score 0):

In the `Course.add` method add a copy of the parameter `student`.

Reason: even a request-scoped bean could get repeated/reused by the container. In every case it is a bit more defensive.